# ngenius-payments payment return - message": "Bad Request

Tags: gateway

When I am calling the API for generating token retune code like this

https://docs.ngenius-payments.com/reference/request-an-access-token-direct

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gg7G.png)

```json
{
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "code": 400,
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Bad token request",
            "localizedMessage": "Bad token request",
            "errorCode": "badTokenRequest",
            "domain": "identity"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your image shows the API and the top 3 headers you are using, but you need to include what your body is and perhaps explain that some details are shown in the image.  I almost didn't click on it because your description of the problem is almost non-existent and there is no description of the image.  Please correct that.

Comment: FYI you need to provide properly-formatted text, not images. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for more details.

Comment: Did you ever find solution on this?

Answer (score -1):

I've encountered the same problem as you recently.

I was missing the "realmName" parameter in the body of my request :

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const ORABANK_API_KEY = process.env.ORABANK_API_KEY;
const ORABANK_REALM_NAME = process.env.ORABANK_REALM_NAME;

const tokenGet = async () => {
  try {
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/vnd.ni-identity.v1+json",
        Authorization: `Basic ${ORABANK_API_KEY}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/vnd.ni-identity.v1+json",
      },
      body: `{"realmName": "${ORABANK_REALM_NAME}"}`,
    };

    const { access_token } = await fetch(
      "https://api-gateway.sandbox.ngenius-payments.com/identity/auth/access-token",
      options
    ).then((response) => response.json());
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

module.exports = tokenGet;
```